# How to rename the ManytoMany Model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, orm, admin, manytomanyfield

I have two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField()
   name = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB)
```

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField()
```

In the Django Admin page, I noticed that I now see a table called "modelA-modelB relationships". Is this the expected outcome?

If so, how can I rename this to be something more user-friendly? I've tried several parameters `verbose_name`, `related_name`, and `db_table` for the `ManytoManyField` and none seem to overwrite the default name.

Comment: You should show the code in admin.py in your app.

Comment: There's nothing special in my `admin.py` besides registering the models. Should there be something in my `admin.py` besides that?